# Are global non-transaction queries strongly consistent on Cloud Firestore in Datastore Mode?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

The following docs page claims:

> Eventual consistency: Datastore queries become strongly consistent
> unless you explicitly request eventual consistency.

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore#in_datastore_mode

But the following docs page seems to say that maybe global non-transactional queries are not strongly consistent:

> The non-transactional read consistency to use. Cannot be set to STRONG
> for global queries.

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rpc/google.datastore.v1#readoptions

What's the correct way to understand this? For example, is an entity is deleted outside a transaction, is it possible for a separate non-transactional query to return that entity afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the docs could use an update, from your second link "For Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode, if read_consistency is not specified then lookups and all queries default to read_consistency=STRONG.".  Queries are strongly consistent for Firestore in Datastore mode unless explicitly requested otherwise.

So if you delete an entity, then start a query that would have matched the deleted entity, the entity will not be returned.

Comment: I have found that if I have a cloud endpoint that reads an entity and adds +1 to a property in it and then saves it, unless I put that read and write into a transaction, it is not strongly consistent with Firestore in Datastore mode (and the count won't be accurate based on how many times the endpoint ran). If I do the same several times in the same endpoint without a transaction, it is indeed strongly consistent. But the latter case is not very useful, since it is more realistic that the endpoint will be executed by different users several times at random times. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Micro, yes you are misunderstanding the need for a transaction.  Your comment isn't related to the question here.